# Xcode displays outlets from multiple projects

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iboutlet

I have a Workspace in which there are two Projects. Both projects contain a ViewController with the same name, but with different IBOutlets. This all works fine while coding, but 'Interface Builder' gets confused.

An example of the situation:

[image: <Project Navigator>]

The contents of both FGViewControllers:

-- MyApp1

```
@interface FGViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *myApp1Outlet;

@end
```

-- MyApp2

```
@interface FGViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIView *myApp2Outlet;

@end
```

When you now open Main.storyboard (either one), in the Connection Inspector both outlets are shown:

[image: <Connection Inspector>]

Is there a way to have Xcode only show the outlets that are located in the project of the storyboard you're editting?

Comment: Looks like a bug, please submit a bug report.

Comment: You're probably right... will do